# Why do I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I do not use any OpenGL stuff in my application (it is a music player), but still, when I run it on my device (Sony Xperia Miro), i get a bunch of errors:
Tag: Adreno200-ES20
Text: < ggl2DrvAPI_glBufferSubData:709 >: GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Can it be a fault in my hardware? This error occurs very often when I run the application.

Comment: Who says it's you that uses OpenGL? Do you use any extrenal libs?

Comment: Yes, I use sliding menu from jeremyfeinstein and Facebook SDK.